# Jenkins unable to find terraform file in dir

Tags: jenkins, terraform

I need to launch few instance on AWS using terraform script, i am automating the whole process using jenkins

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    tools {
        terraform 'terraform'
    }
     stages{
        stage('Git Checkout'){
            steps{
                git branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'gitlab id', url: 'https://gitlab.com/ndey1/kafka-infra'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Terraform init'){
            steps{
                sh 'cd terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc'
                sh 'terraform init'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Terraform plan'){
            steps{
                sh 'terraform plan'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Terraform apply'){
            steps{
                sh 'terraform apply --auto-approve'
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

but while running jenins jobs ( pipeline ) it throws the error

```
+ cd terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc
[Pipeline] sh
+ terraform init
[0m[1mTerraform initialized in an empty directory![0m

The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin working
with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.[0m
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Terraform plan)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ terraform plan
[31m╷[0m[0m
[31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mNo configuration files[0m
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m│[0m [0m[0mPlan requires configuration to be present. Planning without a configuration
[31m│[0m [0mwould mark everything for destruction, which is normally not what is
[31m│[0m [0mdesired. If you would like to destroy everything, run plan with the
[31m│[0m [0m-destroy option. Otherwise, create a Terraform configuration file (.tf
[31m│[0m [0mfile) and try again.
[31m╵[0m[0m
```

though all terraform cod is in the same dir named "kafka-infra" but still its saying no configuration file in dir but terraform init runs successfully , the error comes in the stage of " terraform plan"

Answer (score 2):

The answer was edited as per @NoamHelmer suggestions from the comments.

---

You can use the `dir` option and set it to the directory of the cloned repo, as by default Jenkins is using something called a `workspace` directory.

```
        stage('Terraform init'){
            steps{
                dir("terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc") { // this was added
                    sh 'terraform init'
               }
            }
        }
```

The same line should be added to all the stages.

Or you could alternatively use multiline shell scripts:

```
            steps{
                sh '''
                   cd terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc
                   terraform init
                '''
           }
```

As for the style of the configuration, there are probably multiple (better) ways of doing it. For example, you could use environment variables instead of hardcoding the directory you want to use to execute Terraform code etc.

[1] https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/

[2] https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#dir-change-current-directory

Comment: The `dir` command should be used with a block (`{}`), and also should replace the cd command: `dir('terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc'){ terraform init}`. When using multi line string in your second example the `dir` is not needed.

Comment: stage('Terraform init'){
            steps{
                dir("/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/infra-kaka/terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc")
                
                sh {terraform init}
            }
        }. is this correct ? @NoamHelmer

Comment: @NoamHelmer Thanks, completely forgot about the block part, I edited the answer accordingly. :)

Comment: @NiladriDey see @Marko's edited answer for the syntax, you can also use a path relative to the workspace: `dir('infra-kaka/terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc')`

Comment: stage('Terraform init'){
            steps{
                dir('infra-kafka/terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc')
                
                sh 'terraform init'
            }
        }.    even this command is not working , even it is unable to run terraform init command too.  error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: dir step must be called with a body

Comment: stage('Terraform init'){
            steps{
                dir('infra-kafka/terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc') {
                
                sh 'terraform init'
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Terraform plan'){
            steps{
                dir('infra-kafka/terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc'){
                sh 'terraform plan'
                }
            }
        }
        @MarkoE tried this one now able to run init command but again The directory has no Terraform configuration files.

Comment: @NiladriDey Can you edit the question and add the directory structure of the `terraform-aws-ec2-vpc`?

Comment: Additionally, you said that the code is in the `kafka-infra` directory, but you are still referencing `infra-kaka` in the `dir`. It might be that there is the error.