# Jenkins facing problem to run Terraform code

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, terraform

The project is launching few AWS instances using terraform code and while running through jenkins it throws the following error :

```
    + terraform plan
[31m╷[0m[0m
[31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1merror configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found.
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m│[0m [0mPlease see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws
[31m│[0m [0mfor more information about providing credentials.
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m│[0m [0mError: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
[31m│[0m [0m    For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
[31m│[0m [0m[0m
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m│[0m [0m[0m  with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
[31m│[0m [0m  on provider.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
[31m│[0m [0m   1: provider "aws" [4m{[0m[0m
[31m│[0m [0m
[31m╵[0m[0m
```

This is my pipeline code :

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    tools {
        terraform 'terraform'
    }
     stages{
        stage('Git Checkout'){
            steps{
                git branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'github id', url: 'https://gitlab.com/path/project'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Terraform init'){
            steps{

                
                
                sh 'terraform init'
                
            }
        }
        
        stage('Terraform plan'){
            steps{
                dir('terraform-aws-ec2-with-vpc'){
                
                sh 'ls -ltra'
                sh 'terraform init'
                sh 'terraform plan'
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Terraform apply'){
            steps{
                sh 'terraform apply --auto-approve'
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

in the steps terraform plan its getting failed , not sure, what it means, the .ppk key is already there in gitlab and it also downloaded in /var/lab/jenkins/workspace

Comment: What is your pipeline code?

Comment: @MattSchuchard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68801174/jenkins-unable-to-find-terraform-file-in-dir

Comment: What is your TF code?

Comment: Which stage of the jenkins pipeline throws this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins unable to find terraform file in dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68801174/jenkins-unable-to-find-terraform-file-in-dir)

Comment: @MattSchuchard edited the main question and post the pipeline code

Comment: @lxop in the stage "terraform plan" its getting failed

Comment: @MarkoE , that reference does not answer my question

Comment: @NiladriDey yes, since you completely changed the question, so it's a different problem now. :) As the output shows, you have to provide the Jenkins job valid AWS credentials, probably through environment variables.